# UICollectionView Footers. Read the docs, still can't get one to show. Must be done programmatically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I'm trying to add supplemental footers into a `UICollectionView`.  It seems like I'm hitting all the proper methods according to Apple's documentation but for some reason the:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

...isn't getting called at all.

I've subclassed `UICollectionReusableView` to a class called `SmartActionFooterView`.

In the `ViewController`, in the `ViewDidLoad` method I'm registering and associating views with reuse identifier as such:

```
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[SmartActionFooterView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"footerView"];
```

And then overriding the `UICollectionFlowDelegate` method with...

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
 referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"sizing footer");
    return CGSizeMake(300,100);
}
```

This `NSLog` is printing out.

I'm then hitting the `UICollectionViewDataSource` method...

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSLog(@"Something is happening with the footer...");
SmartActionFooterView *footerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"footerView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

return footerView;
}
```

This `NSLog` however is printing nothing, however I'm at a loss as to why.

I have the constraint of needing to do this all programmatically (no storyboards).

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the outlet `self.collectionView` is properly connected

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to debug and check. Debugging is a very powerful tool in any IDE and it helps most of the times.
What I think you have not done is to set the `datasource` and `delegate` properties of your `UICollectionView` object.

So, try:

```
self.collectionView.datasource = self;
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do have those set in ViewDidLoad, right before registering and associating the views. Still hasn't worked.

Comment: Well i tried with your code and it is working at my end. please put a debug point at viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind method and check is it getting called or not

Comment: I Put a breakpoint in on the viewForSupplementaryOfKind in the ViewDidLoad - breaks properly at this point when running but method itself is never called. I put a breakpoint on the actual method itself as well and nothing happens. NSLog still not printing. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

I was subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout and incorrectly calling:

```
layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath
```

properly in said subclass. The call for this method needed to be done in the:

```
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:
```

and the attributes then passed into a mutable array.

From my understanding of the documents [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW1). The even though the method for creating and dequeueing footers in my View Controller is part of the UICollectionViewDataSource protocol, the datasource first checks with the UICollectionViewFlowLayout to see what objects need to be created.